# How to print a u8 slice as text if I don't care about the particular encoding?

Tags: arrays, string, rust

When printing a `u8` array in Rust using `println!("{:?}", some_u8_slice);` this prints the numeric values (as it should).

What is the most direct way to format the characters as-is into the string
without assuming any particular encoding?

Something like iterating over the byte string and writing each character to `stdout` *(without so much hassle)*.

Can this be done using Rust's `format!`?

Otherwise what's the most convenient way to print a `u8` slice?

Comment: What byte encoding are you assuming? Plain 7-bit ASCII?

Comment: Im not assuming a particular encoding, the text is probably ascii, but not guaranteed to be. I'd just like to see it in the terminal, as if Id written bytes to the stdout. If there is some gibberish because of bad encoding, its OK.

Comment: The question needs to be modified to state that you can't assume any particular encoding. If you can assume UTF-8, that `str::from_utf8` is the best way. Otherwise, `str::from_utf8` fails if it's invalid UTF-8, so you'll need to use other approaches.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to shovel the raw bytes unescaped to stdout, which can be especially useful when the output is redirected to a pipe or a file then following should do the job:

```
let mut out = std::io::stdout();
out.write_all(slice)?;
out.flush()?;
```

The `flush` is necessary since `write_all` immediately followed by a program abort can fail to deliver the bytes to the underlying file descriptor.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way is `stdout().write_all(some_u8_slice)`. This will simply output the bytes, with no regard for their encoding.  This is useful for binary data, or text in some unknown encoding where you want to preserve the original encoding.

If you want to treat the data as a string and you know that the encoding is UTF-8 (or a UTF-8 subset like ASCII) then you can do this:

```
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let some_utf8_slice = &[104, 101, 0xFF, 108, 111];
    if let Ok(s) = str::from_utf8(some_utf8_slice) {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

This will check that the data is valid UTF-8 before printing it.

Comment: While helpful, this is all or nothing - does Rust have something like Python's surrogateescape - python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383 where non decodable sequences still show output? - asked separately:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455206

Comment: More than one person answered your question. You might want to inspect the other answers.

Answer (score 15):

If I can't assume a particular encoding, the way I normally do it is with the [`std::ascii::escape_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/fn.escape_default.html) function. Basically, it will show most ASCII characters as they are, and then escape everything else. The downside is that you won't see every possible Unicode codepoint even if portions of your string are correct UTF-8, but it does the job for most uses:

```
use std::ascii::escape_default;
use std::str;

fn show(bs: &[u8]) -> String {
    let mut visible = String::new();
    for &b in bs {
        let part: Vec<u8> = escape_default(b).collect();
        visible.push_str(str::from_utf8(&part).unwrap());
    }
    visible
}

fn main() {
    let bytes = b"foo\xE2\x98\x83bar\xFFbaz";
    println!("{}", show(bytes));
}
```

Output: `foo\xe2\x98\x83bar\xffbaz`

Another approach is to lossily decode the contents into a string and print that. If there's any invalid UTF-8, you'll get a Unicode replacement character instead of hex escapes of the raw bytes, but you will get to see all valid UTF-8 encoded Unicode codepoints:

```
fn show(bs: &[u8]) -> String {
    String::from_utf8_lossy(bs).into_owned()
}

fn main() {
    let bytes = b"foo\xE2\x98\x83bar\xFFbaz";
    println!("{}", show(bytes));
}
```

Output: `foo☃bar�baz`

Answer (score 3):

The variant using `escape_default()`:

```
use std::ascii::escape_default;

pub fn show_buf<B: AsRef<[u8]>>(buf: B) -> String {
    String::from_utf8(
        buf.as_ref()
           .iter()
           .map(|b| escape_default(*b))
           .flatten()
           .collect(),
    ).unwrap()
}
```