# Is it possible to decode bytes to UTF-8, converting errors to escape sequences in Rust?

Tags: utf-8, rust, unicode-escapes

In Rust it's possible to get UTF-8 from bytes by doing this:

```
if let Ok(s) = str::from_utf8(some_u8_slice) {
    println!("example {}", s);
}
```

This either works or it doesn't, but Python has the ability to handle errors, e.g.:

```
s = some_bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogateescape');
```

In this example the argument `surrogateescape` converts invalid utf-8 sequences to escape-codes, so instead of ignoring or replacing text that can't be decoded, they are replaced with a byte literal expression, which is valid `utf-8`. see: [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) for details.

Does Rust have a way to get a UTF-8 string from bytes which escapes errors instead of failing entirely?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, via [`String::from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy):

```
fn main() {
    let text = [104, 101, 0xFF, 108, 111];
    let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&text);
    println!("{}", s); // he�lo
}
```

If you need more control over the process, you can use [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html), as suggested by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41468380/155423). However, there's no reason to double-validate the bytes as it suggests.

A quickly hacked-up example:

```
use std::str;

fn example(mut bytes: &[u8]) -> String {
    let mut output = String::new();

    loop {
        match str::from_utf8(bytes) {
            Ok(s) => {
                // The entire rest of the string was valid UTF-8, we are done
                output.push_str(s);
                return output;
            }
            Err(e) => {
                let (good, bad) = bytes.split_at(e.valid_up_to());

                if !good.is_empty() {
                    let s = unsafe {
                        // This is safe because we have already validated this
                        // UTF-8 data via the call to `str::from_utf8`; there's
                        // no need to check it a second time
                        str::from_utf8_unchecked(good)
                    };
                    output.push_str(s);
                }

                if bad.is_empty() {
                    //  No more data left
                    return output;
                }

                // Do whatever type of recovery you need to here
                output.push_str("<badbyte>");

                // Skip the bad byte and try again
                bytes = &bad[1..];
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = example(&[104, 101, 0xFF, 108, 111]);
    println!("{}", r); // he<badbyte>lo
}
```

You could extend this to take values to replace bad bytes with, a closure to handle the bad bytes, etc. For example:

```
fn example(mut bytes: &[u8], handler: impl Fn(&mut String, &[u8])) -> String {
    // ...    
                handler(&mut output, bad);
    // ...
}
```

```
let r = example(&[104, 101, 0xFF, 108, 111], |output, bytes| {
    use std::fmt::Write;
    write!(output, "\\U{{{}}}", bytes[0]).unwrap()
});
println!("{}", r); // he\U{255}lo
```

See also:

- [How do I convert a Vector of bytes (u8) to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19076719/155423)
- [How to print a u8 slice as text if I don't care about the particular encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41449708/155423).

Comment: Note that `from_utf8_lossy` doesn't provide different ways of handling errors as Python does. Instead of escaping, invalid utf-8 sequences are replaced with `U+FFFD` (matching Python's `replace` behavior). So I think the short answer to this question is **no**, though its worth mentioning `from_utf8_lossy` still.

Comment: The short answer to either of the posed questions ("Is it possible to decode bytes to UTF-8, converting errors to escape sequences in Rust?" or "Does Rust have a way to get a UTF-8 string from bytes which handles errors without failing entirely?") is **no**? I'm pretty sure that this code does exactly that.

Comment: The docs for `from_utf8_lossy` state: *"During this conversion, from_utf8_lossy() will replace any invalid UTF-8 sequences with U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, which looks like this: �"*. So this is a replacement, not an escape sequence. The first part of this answer shows how converting with an escape sequence could be written: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41450295/432509

Comment: @ideasman42 what do you mean by escape sequence in this case? What's an example?

Comment: Instead of replacing the character, the escape sequence shows the character using some identifier `\N{...}` for example, so instead of being *lossy*, it includes the characters in the string (typically as a number). See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers for some examples. As noted in the OP, Python can use `surrogateescape` for this. Will clarify the question since anyone not familiar with Python won't find it so helpful.

Comment: For the example given in the answer, `bytes([104, 101, 0xFF, 108, 111]).decode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')` would evaluate to `'he\udcfflo'`, with `U+DCFF` being the "escape" character (a code point normally [not valid in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/dcff/index.htm)) used to represent the invalid 0xff byte. Replacing 0xff with 0xfe produces `\udcfe`, and so on.

Comment: @user4815162342 But `surrogateescape` would be completely pointless in Rust; it seems like an alternate implementation of `OsStr`.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't actually work in today's Rust, whose strings and chars reject code points - for example, `"he\u{dcff}lo"` is a compile-time error, and `::std::char::from_u32(0xdcff)` returns `None`.

Comment: The question only asks about escaping the string, not how to perform `surrogateescape` in Rust, thats just an example of a common escaping method used in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. Construct it yourself by using the [strict UTF-8 decoding](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) which returns an error indicating the position where the decoding failed, which you can then escape. But that's inefficient since you will decode each failed attempt twice.
2. Try [3rd party crates](https://crates.io/search?q=charset) which provide more customizable charset decoders.

Comment: *decode each failed attempt twice* — could you expand a bit more on that? I'm not seeing the double decode attempt.

Comment: Re: *"But that's inefficient since you will decode each failed attempt twice."* seems like there should be a better way that can be done in a small function, similar to this answer, but supporting valid utf8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41450295/432509

Comment: @Shepmaster, where do you see it being possible with a single pass in the presence of errors?

Comment: @ideasman42 that better way is the 2nd option I have suggested.

Comment: Starting at the beginning, you parse until you hit an error, skip the error / add whatever marker you need, then continue parsing after the error. You only read each byte once, making a single pass over all the data. Thus why I'm asking what I'm missing.

Comment: @Shepmaster to find the error position you need to call `from_utf8`, then you need to call it again on the prefix to get a valid partial result. so that's 2 passes over the input. in the stdlib there's nothing that takes `u8`s incrementally (a charset decoder basically), which seems to be what OP is looking for.